# Remove special characters from string in Red language

Tags: regex, rebol, red

I want to remove all characters in a string except:

- `-` or `_` or `.`
- `A` thru `Z`
- `a` thru `z`
- `0` to `9`
- space

On linux command line, using `sed` I would do this:

```
$ echo "testing-#$% yes.no" | sed 's/[^-_.a-zA-Z0-9 ]//g'
```

Output:

```
testing- yes.no
```

How can I achieve the same effect in Red language with PARSE?  I looked at:

- http://www.rebol.com/docs/core23/rebolcore-15.html#section-1
- http://rebol-land.blogspot.in/2013/03/rebols-answer-to-regex-parse-and-rebol.html
- http://ross-gill.com/page/Beyond_Regular_Expressions

However, I could not codify it. I tried:

```
>> parse "mystring%^&" [#a - #z #A - #Z #0 - #9]
== false
>> parse "mystring%^&" [#a-#z#A-#Z#0-#9]        
== false
```

Comment: Remember to use `trim` if you want to remove some chars. `trim/with "testing-#$% yes.no" "-#$%."   == "testing yesno"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, characters must be in quotes, `#a` is `issue!`, `char!` is `#"a"`. You've got the specification right, but you must pass it to `charset` function, to make a `bitset!` form it.

Then you can `parse` your string, `keep`ing valid characters and `skip`ing invalid:

```
>> chars: charset [#"a" - #"z" #"A" - #"Z" #"0" - #"9"]
== make bitset! #{000000000000FFC07FFFFFE07FFFFFE0}
>> rejoin parse "mystring%^&asdf" [collect some [keep chars | skip]]
== "mystringasdf"
```

Answer (score 6):

First note the difference between ISSUE! and CHAR!

```
#a #b #c  ; issues
#"a" #"b" #"c"   ; chars
```

You can then establish a character set (BITSET! type) either for the characters you want to keep or those you wish to discard. We'll do the former here:

```
good-chars: charset [#"a" - #"z" #"A" - #"Z" #"0" - #"9"]
```

Now that we have that, we can approach this in some different ways:

## Parse

A fairly basic parse loop—skips any `good-chars` and removes anything else.

```
parse "mystring%^&" [any [some good-chars | remove skip]]
```

## Remove-Each

Hopefully self-explanatory:

```
remove-each char "mystring%^&" [not find good-chars char]
```

Comment: On Red command line, your first answer (parse...) `produces ==true` as output. The second answer (remove-each...) produces no output. Why is this happening?

Comment: @rnso Parse returns **true** if the rule matches. In Red, you can wrap the rule thus: `take parse "mystring%^&" [collect [keep any [some good-chars | remove skip]]]` but that copies the string. Apparently **remove-each** returns the product of the last iteration—in Rebol 2 it would return the modified series. Note that both my answers as-is modify the existing string, they do not create new strings.

Comment: @rnso If your string is set to a word, you can use ALSO: **also mystring parse mystring [any [...]]** or: **also mystring remove-each char mystring [...]**

Comment: Good information. You may add these comments to your answer above since many readers just read answers and not comments.

Comment: @rnso It's implied in that I answered your question as asked. Your chosen answer actually creates several new strings in the process.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative solution to `PARSE` would be to use [`REPLACE`](http://www.rebol.com/r3/docs/functions/replace.html) here with a [`COMPLEMENT`](http://www.rebol.com/r3/docs/functions/complement.html) [`CHARSET`](http://www.rebol.com/r3/docs/functions/charset.html):

```lisp
replace/all "mystring%^&" complement charset [{-_. } #"a" - #"z" #"0" - #"9"] {}
```

NB. Above works in Rebol (2 & 3).  Unfortunately it currently hangs in Red (tested on 0.63 on MacOS).